# Close as Too Localized when the error message is a specific and exact pointer to the problem?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, too-localized

As has been discussed at least a few times, simple syntax errors are generally closed as Too Localized.  The community's common practice seems to have coalesced around this more and more in the past 6 months, which is excellent.

- [Should syntax error questions be closed as too localized after being answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87149/should-syntax-error-questions-be-closed-as-too-localized-after-being-answered)
- [Are questions solved by fixing a typo or basic syntax error "too localized"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137395/are-questions-solved-by-fixing-a-typo-or-basic-syntax-error-too-localized)

Dealing with a specific class of these has left me with doubts, however.  In [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), we see quite a few questions related to the use of unquoted [MySQL reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) as identifiers in queries.  This results in error messages which always look *exactly* like:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THE_RESERVED_KEYWORD

A few of these are common enough that it is a simple matter to search on the error message to locate an already existing duplicate to close against.  The `DESC` keyword, for example [is really common](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%22for+the+right+syntax+to+use+near+%27desc%22&submit=search).  `ORDER` [is also common](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%22for+the+right+syntax+to+use+near+%27order%22&submit=search), anecdotally so are `TO`, `KEY`, `INDEX` and others...

So when one of these is encountered, the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) community can usually spot it immediately.  My instinct is to search on the error message for a duplicate and closevote if I find one.  If I don't find the duplicate I have taken a few different actions:

- Just answer it
- Answer it as community wiki and closevote as Too Localized since it's a syntax error
- Leave a comment pointing to the MySQL docs and closevote as Too Localized (typically I do this now...)

The more I think about it though, closing these as Too Localized seems like the wrong approach.  While it is entirely possible that the OP might have a syntax error in a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, experience tells me that a message like ***"the right syntax to use near 'procedure"*** is indicative of an inappropriate use of a keyword.

**The error message itself then becomes a really valuable clue to finding the *exact cause* of and *solution* to the problem**, unlike variable typos, missed semicolons, or unclosed braces.

Speaking only of the MySQL keywords, there are so many possibilities that it seems unwieldy to create a reference question like the PHP community has done with [the error message reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php), when the solution to the whole class of errors is the same in every case.

---

### So...

**What does the community think is best?** If the error message is specific and exact should we:

- Close as Too Localized (potentially inviting repeats of the same question later on (which may also get closed))
- Answer and build the search reference for future askers (potentially inviting duplication)
- Something else?

Comment: I think I picked the wrong day to ask on meta. Everyone's [preoccupied with hats...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterbash)

Comment: Do we get a hat if we answer your question? If not, I don't even want to look at it :p

Comment: Yay! If we team up together, we can probably achieve a few hats among us! Let's go on an upvote/ask/answer rampage together! Now... did you have a question that is not related to hats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the syntax error can have multiple meanings.

It doesn't give you *what's wrong* in your syntax, just that *it is* wrong.

For that reason, it renders most of these questions "unworthy" (due to the lack of a better term) to be answered. That's because we are not compilers, nor debuggers.

**Any** of these questions can be solved with:

1. A quick glance at the manual.
2. An even quicker Google search.
3. Or, at best, a *decent IDE*.

---

On the other hand, "Too Localized" seems a bit incorrect in this case. Too localized is to be used when a question's universe is so bizarre, so... local, that other users are likely to never reach it. That's usually the case with errors.

When an error becomes a very common thing, one question (the best formulated one) should be answered with a highly detailed, well-explained answer, and the others should be closed as duplicates of that. If there isn't a good one, ask it! And answer it yourself. It doesn't be a catch-all-super-reference question. Something along the lines of:

> ### Why do I get a syntax error when there isn't one in my MySQL query?

Or even more specifically, if you'd like:

> ### Why does using unquoted table/column names trigger a syntax error in MySQL?

Answer (score 9):

I think we should keep such questions opened if the syntax error is common and can't be caught before the execution of the module/method/script/whatever. Your MySQL example just fits that description, whereas a Java type (like a missing `;`) does not.

In your example, I would bet that many developpers have such syntax problems, and spend hours wondering why their apparently perfect script does not work like it should.