# Is the Too Localized close reason being used as a catch all?

Tags: discussion, too-localized

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15214192/397503) was just closed as being too localized. I am assuming that the underlying reason is that this a is syntax error* and only applicable to the poster's situation. As such, it could be construed as having a narrow scope and thus being too localized.

To me this seems to be stretch for something that generally applies to a geographic region or culture. Perhaps, another close reason would be helpful. Maybe something like "Too Long Tail".

*In reality, the poster's problem is not just a syntax error but a fundamental lack of knowledge about SQL.

Comment: "or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet."

Comment: I"d say NARQ is used as catch all, at least that's what it seems like I do.

Comment: See also the dupes for [Are questions about syntax errors too localized?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160275/135887) and [Close as Too Localized when the error message is a specific and exact pointer to the problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159317/135887).

Answer (score 11):

It could also be considered "not a real question", but I can understand why it was closed as "too localized". Consider the definition of NARQ:

> **not a real question** It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.
>   This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or
>   rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For
>   help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

- Is difficult to tell what is being asked? **No**. It basically says "I'm having this error, here is my code, what's wrong? That's almost the same as "fix that for me plz".
- Is it ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical? **No**.
- Can it be answered in its current form? **Yes**, and it was. Whether it should be answered or not is another discussion.

Now, look at the definition of too localized:

> **too localized** This question is unlikely to help any future visitors;
>   it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in
>   time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally
>   applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making
>   this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

The first sentence is important: it's **unlikely to help any future visitors**; in its current form, it applies to **an extraordinarily narrow situation**, which is the problem the OP is facing. It's very unlikely someone facing a similar problem will find that (look at the title!) and find it helpful.

So I do believe "too localized" is a better fit for "gimme teh codez" or "fix this for me", and general syntax error/typo questions.