# Dealing with "I need code" people

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Sometimes, [people like these come up in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16641312/575527) (Not me, but the OP and how he replies to the comments). I have placed MDN links and support tables, as well as a demo of how to get the `length` of the returned data, but doesn't seem to check them out. It's because *he needs it right there*.

How do you deal with these "I need" people? Should these people be banned or something?

Comment: aka, "help vampires". Downvote -> close -> burn. :):):)

Comment: Wow - this guy is more obnoxious than the typical help vampire.

Comment: That's what you officially call them? "Help Vampires"? LOL

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer The term comes from: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Comment: I think that, unfortunately, the problem with your demo is the use of `console.log`. I imagine the OP has no idea what the console is, let alone how to use it. He's probably looking at your demo and not seeing `length` displayed anywhere because he doesn't know where to look. Not meaning to make light of your efforts, mind you - you've already put in far more effort that you should have had to.

Comment: @Mac The OP uses `console.log()` in the question.

Comment: @jprofitt: so he does. There goes that theory... :)

Comment: Which means no effort at all. Just looked at the code, not even trying to make sense of it.

Comment: @Mac Don't worry, I'm sure there's some other "not understanding a fundamental" in there somewhere. Or everywhere.

Comment: The less a questioner is willing to do their own homework/effort/research, the less you should be willing to help them. Simple as that. Not every question needs answering on S/O.

Answer (score 7):

I put this in the same category as the people who post questions without example data/code/etc. or detail enough to figure the problem out ('mind reader' questions).  The amount of effort spent answering the question should be linearly related to the constructive effort put forth by the asker.

If the asker writes a clear, concise, well thought out question, I'm willing to put a lot of effort into answering it.  If the asker is polite and courteous in comments/replies, I am willing to put a lot of effort into clarifying points he/she does not understand.

If the asker writes a complicated, hard to understand question with no effort put into it, I will only bother to answer it if it's something I have the answer already at hand for.  If the asker then proceeds to be insulting, rude, or irritating in the comments, I won't put much effort into replying.

I figure not only is this positive feedback for me (I spend more time on questions/answers that make me happy), but it's positive feedback for the community - if a few of the annoying ones don't get answers or don't understand their answers, we're better off without them, as that means we can more easily help those that *do* need and want help, and are willing to help us help them.

Answer (score 5):

Put the amount of effort *you* want to into answering the question. If it is not an acceptable answer to the OP you're allowed to ignore them.

If they're being obnoxious or whatever, mark the comments or question for moderator attention.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone ask code in question such type of question should be burn with fire

[image]

<sub>[image from pekka's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160275/are-questions-about-syntax-errors-too-localized#comment464485_160275)</sub>