# Close as "Unlikely to help anyone else" (was "too localized" before)

Tags: discussion

While the recently revised "offtopic" reasons are quite good, I am missing some counterpart of what was "Too localized" before.

I would like to have some close reason like this for cases where someone asks a question with a provided code showing the problem, but the problem shows up to be some trivial mistake or oversight in the code. Recent example of such question is [Memory error while using memcpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232900/memory-error-while-using-memcpy).

Comment: I'm not sure writing `new UInt8(...)` instead of `new UInt8[...]` actually qualifies as a *trivial mistake or oversight*. This is not a syntax error or obvious design mistake, and results in valid but wrong code that crashes at runtime. That question can help someone else IMHO. I would not close it.

Comment: Well, I think the answer to the question I suggest this is a duplicate of explains this perfectly: "the problem described is totally separate from the actual problem". There is no problem with memcpy, or the buffer addressing, the problem is in the part of the code the OP did not even consider could be buggy.

Answer (score 8):

I'm hesitant to close questions that are typo questions (e.g., "Too Localized") [unless they meet very specific criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186181/now-that-too-localized-is-gone-should-we-embrace-the-typo-questions/186196#186196).

One reason [is that I was recently helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263495/django-invalid-block-tag-endfor-expected-endblock) by what could be considered a 'typo' or 'too localized' question.

I was rushing through the code in Vim, and just didn't pick up on my mistake.  I double checked, triple-checked, and everything looked correct, so I googled, and found the above question and answer. I checked the code block, and it was absolutely spot on.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any harm in leaving questions alone that are 'too localized'. It is impossible to say that they will never help anyone else.