# Should typo questions be closed as localized?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, too-localized

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should questions where a problem arose from a typo be closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123741/should-questions-where-a-problem-arose-from-a-typo-be-closed)

Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10171390/561731) are answered due to a typo by the OP.

Should these types of questions be closed as too localized?

I have seen many different types of typo questions....

Comment: They should, but in practice they aren't. Maybe that's something the review queues may be able to change though.

Comment: Lovely irony "due to a type by the OP".

Comment: @AndrewC bahh. :-P