# Declined flag in helpful flags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, declined-flags, helpful-flags

In my helpful flags (on profile page), there is a declined flag, which doesn't seem right.
Is this a bug?

Here's the flag:
[image: Image of flag]

**This flag comes in my helpful flags**
I did realize that the flag was not meant for such answers, but then how is the declined flag among my Helpful Flags page

Comment: We can't see you flag history. Please give details of declined flag.

Comment: In short, why wouldn't it be right?

Comment: @J.Steen Well how is a flag helpful, if it was declined??

Comment: Ah - you mean the TEXT in the user profile. Be a *little* more clear that you mean a typo. =)

Comment: @J.Steen [Close all the typo questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions)! ;-)

Comment: Helpful flags = Total flags - (Declined | Disputed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the link in your profile states "helpful flags" which relates to the number behind it, the page it leads you to is the "Flagged Posts" page. It will contain both the helpful and declined flags. As such this is not a bug.

Comment: Well, Now I see that.. The link should not be on `helpful flags` but on something like `Flags` or `Flagged Posts` instead...

Answer (score 3):

It appears you flagged this:

> You are using two if statements one after the other in the running loop. Try using an if and elif statement instead.

It **is an answer** - it may be wrong / not very good, but it is an *answer* in the sense it's not "Oh - I got this problem as well - did you fix it?" or "Hi, do you like dogs?" etc...

You're of course welcome to downvote such answers.

**In answer to comment:**

> Yes, but why is it a helpful flag??

It's not - "helpful flags" is just the terminology used on your profile page. The flag will normally have next to it "helpful" (as in it was helpful), "declined" (it wasn't deemed helpful) as yours shows, or possibly "disputed" which because of the way the system works means opposing flags from multiple users can't be split helpful/declined appropriately, so end up "disputed"

Answer (score 0):

As Bar mentioned in his answer, the link on your profile says Helpful Flags and contains only the list of flags that are helpful - and not the declined ones or event the ones pending review.

You click on the link and you reach a page titled Flagged Posts for username. Here you get to see details of all your flags, helpful, declined and pending.

The flag in your question is not helpful and SO does not claim it is.