# Order a search by oldest close votes?

Tags: feature-request, search

I'm trying to help with the effort in [Close all the typo questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions).  Is there a way that order the results of a search to have oldest-close-votes (those nearest to expiring) at the top of the results? Or is there a way to add number of close votes to the search critera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not index the number of close votes on a question (nor would how we store them trigger a re-index), so no...sorting by this isn't possible.  You would need to use [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) or [our public data dump](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump) to perform such a query.

Answer (score -1):

To show oldest results first use **Order By** in Query. Like...

```
select a.Id as [Post Link], a.Body
from Posts q
inner join Posts a on a.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId -- only check accepted answers
where len(a.Body) < 200 -- posts less than 200 chars can be a giveaway
and q.ClosedDate IS NULL -- only search open questions
and (
      lower(a.Body) like '%typo%'
   or lower(a.Body) like '%spelled wrong%'
   or lower(a.Body) like '%spelled incorrectly%' -- add more...
)
Order By a.ID Desc
```

See the last line **Order By a.ID Desc**