# Should Close Votes review queue be presented 'oldest first'?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

When reviewing Close Votes, it looks as if they are presented from the most recent back in time. Do I see this correctly?
(If this premise is incorrect my question can be closed right now ;-) because of the [accepted answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129848/order-suggested-edit-queue-by-oldest-first-rather-than-randomly))

The discussion in [Close Review Queue - recent questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148213/close-review-queue-recent-questions) discusses the 'closing too quickly' of recent questions.
The answers are basically 'improve the question by editing or commenting' or 'just vote to close, the OP can edit the question' and this has been further strengthened by rewording the [closed] status to [on hold].

Still, I feel I have to take into account how old the question is: for a recent one I will put more effort in 'educating the OP' in the hope that it becomes a decent question (often it's just insufficient information); for an old one I will just vote to close.

Given the size of the review queue, working from old to new would speed up the review process for me, because I don't have to put effort in the 'education'.
(As do other techniques like e.g. [mentioned here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow))

Therefore: shouldn't the Close Votes be presented 'oldest first'?
(That currently [does not seem possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169538/order-a-search-by-oldest-close-votes))

Comment: I don't have time to dig up the reference, but I'm pretty sure there's a post by Shog explaining that questions with more reviews (either close votes or reviews) are tossed through first to clear them out. Since many new questions get several close votes prior to the review queue, they may be thrown in well before very old low-view questions with 1-2 close votes. Just a hypothesis.

Comment: I think it's much more important to be closing the new stuff, new stuff is what is visible, all the 2012 questions are out of sight anyway.