# In what order are questions in the close queue presented to a user. and why are they presented in that order?

Tags: discussion, review

I am very curious about the factors which determine the order in which a specific reviewer is presented with questions in the "close" queue. I ask about the close queue, because on mathematics.se, there are always questions in the close queue.  On a typical "new" day, my close-queue reviews begin at a time when, say, 165 questions are in the close queue.

When I click on "close" to review questions with at least one pending close vote, what factors determine the order in which the 165 questions are presented to me?

I suppose there may be some randomness in the order of presentation of those questions; it was also suggested that perhaps questions whose tags overlap with tags that I frequent may be a factor.

I've sort of ruled out "those with the most close votes in the review queue are presented first, whoever the reviewer is" (because my experience reviewing reveals too many counterexamples).  I haven't been able to determine whether or not they are presented from newest to oldest in the queue, or vice versa.  (Note, I have reviewed well over 20,000 posts from the close queue on MSE).

Any clarification about why and how I'm presented with the questions to review for closure, in the order I receive them, until I've either voted to close or keep open 20 posts, would be appreciated.

My question is relevant for any specific reviewer.  I merely used myself to help simplify the question.  I realize that which questions user x may see first, may not be those that user y sees first, but I'm wondering what factors play into the presentation of questions to review for any particular user.

---

Note: If the order of questions presented in the close queue varies from site to site, please let me know, and if so, I will withdraw my question readily.

---

Additional note: I have read [this post about whether questions in the review queues should be presented from oldest, to most recent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217849/should-close-votes-review-queue-be-presented-oldest-first?rq=1), and there was a comment suggesting that in fact, questions are presented from most recent to oldest. That comment also referenced an explanation from @Shog9 on this matter, but did not provide a link to it.