# I would like to understand why I lost 8 points for something

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

This isn't a complaint but I would like to know what the following means:

[image]

I understand a post was removed and I lost 8 points but does this mean an answer or a question? Is there any way to find out why? Could it mean a post I answered was removed and I lost points for an upvoted answer?

p.s Excuse the tagging, I didn't know how to classify this.

Comment: If an answer with one upvote and one downvote is removed, the loss of both +10 and -2 on that would result in a -8 change. (Guess it could also be a question with two upvotes and one downvote.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your answer to [this deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341192/ajax-post-is-not-being-sent) (10k+ users only) was deleted together with the question.

You received 1 up- and 1 downvote for it at the time, giving you a +8 reputation change in total. When it was deleted, the reputation gain was removed again as well.

The question was closed and deleted as too localized as part of the [typo clean-up effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions).

Comment: Ah, so it was the question that was removed not necessarily a bad action on my part?

Comment: @webnoob Exactly.

Comment: @webnoob: Indeed.

Comment: Ok guys, many thanks. I just wanted to make sure I understand.