# There is a problem of laziness or "disappearance" of the person who asks the question

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, ethics, feedback, original-poster

From my observation, many people ask something and simply go away. They sometimes even receive 3–4 answers, take the codes, and run away without commenting anything, without voting anything, and without picking any answer.

Is this a normal thing? (Is the forum not interactive in finding a solution?)

If it's not normal, what should be done against it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is rather normal for new users.

Comment: Hmm, this is ironic. Aren't you the same person who just asked two questions and then deleted both of them? Oh yes, yes you are.

Comment: So what? They still "disappeared". Duplicate doesn't mean "delete me".

Comment: Cody, what does that have to do with this topic? I propose something, you come and tell me "OH YES YOU ARE , YOU ARE".. wtf? , man.

Comment: Unless you have something to suggest as new feature please don't use the [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: You are complaining about people who ask questions disappearing. I'm complaining about *the questions themselves* disappearing. I think it's far worse when questions disappear than when the person who originally asked that question disappears.

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu Just a word of advice: duplicate questions are not necessarily bad. There's no need to delete them. And if you frequently delete questions, especially once that are closed and downvoted, you might run into an automatic question ban. That's more difficult on Meta, but not impossible. So don't make it a habit.

Comment: There is a difference of opinion between Ali and Cody on the merits of deleting a question simply because it has been marked duplicate.  I'm with Cody.  The question might still have positive value.  The votes are a better indicator of value.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but be aware that [downvotes are different on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187018/voting-on-meta-is-not-just-for-disagreement-update-the-help-center-to-reflect/191880#191880).

Comment: @Bart thanks, updated the comment. I keep losing track of the most recent version of that discussion...

Comment: weird, the question has 3x audience in comparison to other recent questions, it's an important subject, but gets minus all the time :) I love my downvoters

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu Top tip: complaining about downvotes on Meta usually results in more of them.

Comment: @Bart no problem, it's entertaining to keep track, at least you guys couldn't flag it as duplicate this time ...:P

Comment: [Are you sure @AliCarikcioglu](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177288/stack-overflow-is-a-site-of-passers-by)? .... :)

Comment: @Bart.. lol....

Comment: You seriously, seriously, seriously need to learn some *patience*. Not only do you continually complain about people not *instantly*, positively responding to your posts, you have a *massive* number of posts (questions and answers) that you have deleted almost immediately when you didn't immediately get the response you wanted.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Mind your own business, it's not related to topic above.

Comment: 1) I am minding my own business. 2) I did check the topic above; you actually are pretty much *the worst* offender here; 'disappearing' constantly.

Comment: @AndrewBarber check the answers below. the disappearance is considered not a problem :)

Comment: Oh; and I love your pre-edit comment. Good thing you edited it so quickly ;)

Comment: The constant deletion of content is however. [I have explained the possible ban to you before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193205/there-is-a-problem-of-lazyness-or-disappearance-of-the-person-who-asks-the-que#comment604741_193205).

Comment: @Bart yes and the topic here is deletion or being idle?

Comment: @Ali What he's saying is that you're complaining about something that you do.

Comment: Doorknob: I complain about people who ask a question and don't bother to read the answers. Did I ask a question and didn't read the answers?

Comment: No, you [did this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193190/disable-flagging-own-message) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193199/show-some-tooltip-to-remind-the-asker-that-he-can-or-should-select-the-bes).

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu You've never given people the *time* to read the answers. You go on rampages when people don't respond quickly enough for your tastes. You have called people names when they didn't vote/accept your answers quickly enough for you (while having done nothing else whatsoever). You have deleted your posts within *minutes* because you didn't get an accept/vote as quickly as you thought you should...

Comment: Just wondering...how is not a moderators business on a site he moderates?

Comment: @MichaelGrubey When the person in question doesn't like what the moderator has to say ;)

Comment: @MichaelGrubey Let's just say that we should be glad that's the version of the comment that now remains.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey he told me about this yesterday, before the question was even posted :) now came here, wrote the same under another topic :) and wrote the same again 3rd time :)

Comment: I Want him to say the same thing again :)

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu Have you not heard...unicorns around here can predict the future o_O

Comment: @Ari Deleting a large portion of your questions *minutes* after posting is *much*, **much** worse.

Comment: @Doorknob maybe :) but still nothing to do with topic above :)

Comment: @Ari It has everything to do with the topic - you say that there's a problem with users not reading answers, when you yourself don't read then either. Anyway this is a pointless discussion so this is my last comment here.

Comment: @Doorknob Deleting something means that I think that thing was not worth enough to post. Being idle, going away means, lazyness, idle, disappearance..

Comment: So then the question is, why are you posting things in the first place that you think are "not worth enough to post"?

Comment: Cody because after moderator shows me a duplicate, it loses importance.

Comment: @Ali, [Do not delete duplicates!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32311/164403)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is this a normal thing?

Yes.  While it's not how we'd *like* people to interact on Stack Exchange sites, it happens often enough that I wouldn't say that it's abnormal.

> ...what should be done against it?

Nothing special.  If the question can be answered without the author's input, go ahead and answer it.  The site is really here for other people to use as a repository of good <strike>programming</strike> information anyway, so it doesn't matter if the OP skips town.  Other people can still benefit.  If the question can't be answered without the OP, just vote to close it and it will eventually be deleted.

Comment: thank you for ordered answers.

Answer (score 10):

I don't see this as a problem. Our goal here is to build up a collection of high-quality expert answers to a wide variety of programming questions. We need people to ask questions in order to attract those answers, but it doesn't really matter if the person who asked that question hangs around.

Yes, it would be nice if new users would upvote and accept answers that they find helpful. Most of the time they do—at least in my experience, and you didn't present any evidence to the contrary. But for those who don't, there is little we can do to force them to do something they don't want to do.

And I can't imagine why we would want to. This is, after all, a free Q&A site. If you want to ask a question, get an answer, and then disappear, you're perfectly welcome to do so. Stack Overflow is not a social network, it's not a lifestyle, and it doesn't have to be a long-term committment.

The really important thing is that the *question* continues to hang around, along with its answers, so that other people with the same problem can find it later and benefit from the accumulated wisdom.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's a normal thing. Unfortunately part of the site's strength (finding answers to your questions) is also a partial cause of this problem. Users have questions that need answers. And they get their answers here, and they get them fast. They are not necessarily interested in the wider community, the site's goals or even it's rules and regulations.

And if their questions are good, that to some extent is just fine. We worry about good content. We can't force anyone to actively participate. Is it annoying that your answer does not get accepted, even when it's provably the best and probably helped the OP? Sure, if only for the symbolic meaning of that green tick mark. But in the great scheme of things, it doesn't matter all that much. If your answers are good, the community will evaluate and appreciate them.

Should something be done about such users? I'd say not. Just evaluate their questions. If they are good, welcome the content. If they are bad, either improve if possible, or vote accordingly.