# Can this question be undeleted?

Tags: support, undelete-request

User said my answer had helped him, and then deleted the question instead of accepting an answer. Can this question be undeleted?

[How to store or print data of submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890945/how-to-store-or-print-data-of-submit-button/16891003)?

Comment: I say we burn the user...

Comment: @Pekka웃: Is that question really that good? The title let's me assume otherwise...and if there was sarcasm, then I apologize, it's monday morning and I don't have 10k on SO (really need to work on that)...

Comment: It wasn't a *great* question, but I think the solution based on the symptoms could easily be useful to other visitors.

Comment: The answer (with OP's comment) reads to me to like this is a [typo question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions), @Pekka웃. While I don't like to see a question deleted by the asker right after it's answered, I think this one would end up deleted _anyways_. It shouldn't have gone this way, but I don't see the point in undeleting, closing, and redeleting.

Comment: @Josh that's a fair point, for some reason I didn't realize that. I retract my comment

Comment: @ColeJohnson Does he weigh the same as a duck?

Comment: @dmckee No, but [s]he turned me into a newt, then I got better...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the questions can be undeleted by users with access to 10k-tools.

However, I don't think that the question is beneficial to any future users. As per a quite famous (and much recent) campaign of [removing all typo questions from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342/212576), I'll quote from [random's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167344/212576) reply:

> A typo is not the same as a logic problem and seeing results turn up
>   for the former when yours is clearly of the latter is indeed a cycle
>   of bother.