# What constitutes a typo?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, spelling

After reading about the campaign to close questions pertaining to typos, I have to ask, what constitutes a typo? For example, I'm learning about writing shell scripts in Linux, bash, etc. Apparently, bash is *really* picky about syntax and as such

```
var = 5
```

is wrong, while

```
var=5
```

is right. Took me a while to realize what I was doing wrong (had this same problem with if's and loops) and SO questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781290/syntax-error-in-while-loop-bash) were very useful in figuring out the issue. However, that question's answer ("You forgot the spaces") seems to me to be along the same lines of "you forgot a semicolon". Are questions such as this going to be closed? I feel there's a difference between someone forgetting a single item they should know (such as a brace or semicolon) and helping to explain the nuances of syntax. I would really like to keep these kinds of questions around. Where does the line lie?

(Apologies if a more concrete answer has already been decided. I looked at [the initial request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions), but didn't see more than talking about single character issues)

Comment: You are not talking about typos. You are talking about code formatting. A typo would be 'lenght', for example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The example you mention isn't really a typo.  A typo is a spelling mistake, caused by swicthing lteters aorund, omtting ltters, or innsreting addiitional onnes.

The bash error above is a syntax error more than anything else.

In other languages, it's more a point of style and readability, and is neither a typo nor a syntax error.

It might be good to begin socializing the definitions of each kind of correction:

- correcting a typo
- correcting a syntax error
- improving readability by adding/removing whitespace

They're not interchangeable IMO.

Comment: BoltClock:  Thanks for the edit.  Much more readable. ;)

Answer (score 7):

When you vote to close on such things it's normally closed as **Too Localized**, or, you don't think that it will help future users or cause the OP to learn more about the language.

So, if you can (reasonably) imagine people thinking `oh, I didn't know that detail about bash syntax` then it's **not** too localized, but if it's always `oh, it's just a spelling error` then it **is** too localized.

Actually think about whether the typo matches the **spirit** of the reason.  You don't have to just vote to close everything that you think is a typo.  You're not a robot.