# Should we answer or comment on a typo question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, low-quality-posts

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123741/should-questions-where-a-problem-arose-from-a-typo-be-closed), questions with a typo or syntax error should be closed. However we still have to address the issue where the OP has made a mistake. Where is the best place to respond to him, in the comments or in an answer?

This question, [syntax error line 21 php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730347/syntax-error-line-21-php), is obviously about a syntax error. I left a comment saying where the problem is, and voted to close it as "too localized". However, a user with the close vote privilege chose to give an answer, repeating what was in my comments.

Should we answer the typo question, possibly gaining a few reps, or just leave a comment and close it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I guess most of us current high-rep users are guilty of having answered these kinds of questions at some point in the past, and gaining rep points for it (I know I have) so discouraging the practice now feels slightly hypocritical. Still: the *classy* thing to do is absolutely to post only a comment, or a CW answer, and vote for the question to be closed. I'd advise against posting an answer (but is a legitimate thing to do).