# User self answers, doesn't mark as answered nor deletes...what next and by whom?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, self-answer

While researching a topic I came across an answer which the user answered his own post with an answer but didn't mark it as answered. I felt it should be put to rest by most likely deleting it due to its content, or if not marking the user's answer as the answer.

What should be done, or should I do at this point?

According to meta stackoverflow a question  should be

> deleted with extreme prejudice

as per Jeff Atwood's answer to  [Should self-answered "It was something stupid I was doing" questions be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90686/should-self-answered-it-was-something-stupid-i-was-doing-questions-be-deleted)

I don't have that ability at my level to mark the user's answer as answer, nor delete it so I flagged it for a Moderator. The day the moderator stated

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention

Maybe I didn't make myself clear to the moderator, *which is possible*, but shouldn't the moderator either delete the post or make the user's answer the answer?

Initiating Post: [Azure, edit in visual studio online option - gone missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429932/azure-edit-in-visual-studio-online-option-gone-missing/20430701#20430701)

Comment: There is no need for an answer to be marked accepted.  It doesn't actually serve any purpose

Comment: There is no need for an answer to be verified to be correct.  It only has to be popular.

Comment: @RichardTingle - There is one purpose - if you are looking for unanswered questions to answer, then these are false positives.

Comment: @Corley they are only considered "unanswered" if there are no upvoted (or accepted) answers, if its not worth an upvote the question isnt really answered to any acceptable degree. Personally I never accept my own answers because it says (a) I think my answer is already perfect,  I won't consider others and (b) who am I to give myself a big pat on the back, if people think the answer is good they'll upvote it, if not they won't

Comment: @Corley absolutely, stack exchange questions are forever, not just for the OP. The same reason you might add an answer years after its answered;  its not likely to help the OP but may help other people who find the question

Comment: @RichardTingle - understood (deleted other comment after I realized OP was actually talking about an answer, not a comment). So, if original questioner answers own question, but never gets upvotes, it probably isn't a very good answer, and so still maybe worth writing another answer, if the question is good enough.

Comment: Are there *any* cases where an answer should be marked as accepted by someone other than the user who asked the question? Do moderators even have that ability?

Answer (score 6):

Please read the post with Jeff's answer you linked more carefully:

> Category 1: Never Mind
>
> Category 2: I'll give you a hint but not my solution

That post was specifically talking about self-answers that aren't solutions. This self-answer did provide a solution (turn on the switch in the config pane), therefore there's no reason to delete it.

This is essentially no different than an answer from someone else with a "thanks, that helped" comment and no accept, and the action taken should be exactly the same: a helpful comment towards the OP explaining how accepting answers works.

Comment: Sidenote: such a comment would most likely be futile at this point since the user hasn't been seen for 3 months