# I have a stupid self-answered question. Should I accept my own answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, self-answer

[This question which I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615026/adding-texlive-to-texstudios-understanding-of-path) was genuine at the time, but I realised that [the solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133235/installing-tex-live-2013-on-linux) gave the right advice, but required me to restart my Linux (which wasn't mentioned in the solution).

It's a bit of a ["it was something stupid I was doing"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90686/should-self-answered-it-was-something-stupid-i-was-doing-questions-be-deleted?lq=1) question and [the discussion on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90754/253241) points to me not deleting it.

But it seems hugely self-aggrandizing to accept my own answer. Should I?

Comment: You won't get points for it but if your own answer was the most helpful post then why not?

Comment: You can also community wiki it if you don't want any rep from any upvotes that the answer may attract.

Comment: People come to SO (or Google, more likely) because they have an issue that they're looking for the solution to. I wouldn't be surprised if people don't even notice the avatar and name associated to Qs and As. But they will notice the answer that comes at the top of the list of answers, so if that is the correct one then mark it as such to help these visitors out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if you think the question and answer will ever be useful to other people, you should accept your answer. That sends a clear message that "this is what I did to solve the problem in the question." If one person has that problem, odds are other people will too, no matter how [silly you feel for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/638975/1288).